# Haskell: Evalute String containing a simple arithmetic expression to Int

Tags: haskell

I am learning Haskell, and I encounter a tricky problem which is evaluating String containing a simple arithmetic expression like (+) and (-) to int. 
Take some for example:
"1+2+3" -> 6 , " " -> 0 .
I am trying to type the code. However, I cannot complete that. The following is my code.

```
evalExpr xs  = foldl f 0 xs where
 f acc x | x == "+" =  (+) acc
         | x == "-" =  (-) acc
         | x == " " = 0
         | otherwise = read x ::Int
* In the expression: read x :: Int
  In an equation for `f':
      f acc x
        | x == "+" = (+) acc
        | x == "-" = (-) acc
        | x == " " = 0
        | otherwise = read x :: Int
  In an equation for `evalExpr':
      evalExpr xs
        = foldl f 0 xs
        where
            f acc x
              | x == "+" = (+) acc
              | x == "-" = (-) acc
              | x == " " = 0
              | otherwise = read x :: Int
* Relevant bindings include
    acc :: a1 (bound at A2.hs:24:8)
    f :: a1 -> [Char] -> a1 -> a1 (bound at A2.hs:24:6)
```

Could someone help me? Thank you!

Comment: What is the type of `f`?

Comment: @pat I felt confused, the code is just my thought.

Comment: @pat I want the last accumulator becomes the Int. The median acc might contains operators like + or -

Comment: Your types are wrong. What's your actual question?

Comment: @AJFarmar evaluate string to int . example: “1+2” -> 3

Comment: @zhengzhong that is not a question, that is an instruction. Please ask a question. We're not going to write your code for you.

Comment: @AJFarmar the type of f is wrong, but how do i change that, I want the output of f is type of Int.

Comment: @zhengzhong Writing `0` produces a different type to other results of `f`; change it.

Comment: @AJFarmar which 0? if you said the type of f should be fixed, how do I deal with the operator which makes accumulator to be a function.

Comment: Your `x == " "` and `otherwise` lines return values of type `Int`, but the `x == "+"` and `x == "-"` lines return `(+) acc` and `(-) acc`, which are both of type `Num a => a -> a`. You need to change your code so that all four lines return the same type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is that the result type of `f` is different in different branches, which is not allowed. In the first two it is (e.g.) `Int -> Int`, the type of `(+) 3` (which is the same as `\x -> 3 + x`. The type of the third and fourth lines is just `Int`. These types are not the same.

Here is a simple solution.

```
data Token = Plus | Minus | Num Int 
lex [] = Nothing
lex ('+':s) = Just (Plus,s)
lex ('-':s) = Just (Minus,s)
lex (num:s) | isDigit num = Just (Num k,rest) where
  numstr a (d:s) | isDigit d = numstr (digitVal d:a) s
  numstr a r = a,r
  digits,rest = numstr [digitVal num] s
  k = foldr 0 (\acc d -> acc*10 + d) digits

parse s = case lex s of
  Nothing -> []
  Just (x,s') -> x:parse s'

eval (Num n:r) = eval (Plus:Num n:r)
eval = eval' 0 where
  eval' acc (Plus:Num n:r) = eval' (acc+n) r
  eval' acc (Minus:Num n:r) = eval' (acc-n) r
```

Comment: Thank you very much, i will look at that.